# error creating bean with name 'processName' defined in classpath [activiti.cfg.xml] ...No default constructor found

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, junit4, activiti

I am trying to run a unit test for a simple process in activiti but I keep getting an exception. I've searched and believe the problem is in the **activiti.cfg.xml** file itself, it expects a constructor but it has a property instead. The test was auto generated and the **activiti.cfg.xml** file as well. So I want to know what should I change to make it work.

This is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration">
        <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And this is the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngineConfiguration' defined in class path resource [activiti.cfg.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ibatis/type/TypeHandler
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1228)
```

Comment: Would you add source of `StandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration` class? Does it have a default constructor?

Comment: The StandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguratio class comes in the org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg package. This is the code

Comment: package org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg;

/**
 */
public class StandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration extends StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration {

  public StandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration() {
    this.databaseSchemaUpdate = DB_SCHEMA_UPDATE_CREATE_DROP;
    this.jdbcUrl = "jdbc:h2:mem:activiti";
  }
}

Comment: Your main exception is: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ibatis/type/TypeHandler` So @Faron 's answer may be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a dependency in your classpath. Check that you have [mybatis](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/) available.

Comment: I added the dependency now I am getting this error:

Comment: org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Error while building ibatis SqlSessionFactory: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Illegal overloaded getter method with ambiguous type for property processInstance in class class org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity. This breaks the JavaBeans specification and can cause unpredictable results.

Comment: @thesivar This is another error and you need to accept Faron's post as answer and post another question for your new problem.